# .Net Core and *.msg Files

Tags: email, .net-core

Does anyone know a libary for reading msg-files with .Net-Core?

I assume that there is no such libary yet aviable for .Net-Core to work with msg-files, so maybe a open-source libary for .Net-Framework, which I can use to rewrite the code for .Net-Core?

Or maybe some other *trick* to read the msg-file content would maybe help me a lot.

I need to parse the content of the msg-file and provide the content in our API for other applications.

Regards

Comment: Is there code you were using in .NET Framework that uses types that no longer exist? Or is this a fresh problem that you're asking for a library recommendation on (which is considered off-topic on StackOverflow)?